# how to specify namespace in ClassMapGenerator

Tags: symfony, autoloader

I am using the following code to create `ClassMapGenerator::createMap('../something/nadlib')`

The output I get is something like this

```
array (size=1)
  'dbLayer' => string '/srv/www/public/debagsuy/ris/vendor/nadlib/nadlib/DB/class.dbLayer.php'
```

My problem is that I have multiple folders to import

```
ClassMapGenerator::createMap(['../something/nadlib', '../something/secondlibrary'])
```

and if the second folder has a class at the same level called `'dbLayer'` one of them is getting overridden

Is it possible to provide Namespace to `ClassMapGenerator`?

So that the output looks like

```
array (size=1)
  '**Nadlib/dbLayer**' => string '/srv/www/public/debagsuy/ris/vendor/nadlib/nadlib/DB/class.dbLayer.php'
```

Comment: Do you make use of namespaces in your classes?

Comment: no unfortunately not the code is from 2003

Comment: Then you have to rewrite your code. You cannot have to classes in the same namespace (without an explicit `namespace` directive the default namespace is assumed).